# Display text as background width increases?

Tags: html, css

I want the text in the blue box to appear on its opening, but it should be fixed, not adjusting to the blue box width. 
I also need some ideas as to what can be other interesting ways to display the text in a similar manner that I just did. (ie not visible initially but on hovering, text visible)

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
p {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#page1 {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #77d47f;
}
#about {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 width: 504px;
 height: 100px;
}
#about_button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
}
#about_text {
 transition: width 0.5s;
 height: 100px;
 width: 0;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
 transform: translateX(-4px);
 overflow: hidden;
}
#about {
 top: 10%;
}

#about_button:hover + #about_text {
 width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="page1">
   <div id="about">
       <div id="about_button"></div>
    <div id="about_text"><p>Hi, I am a Computer Science student. I am interested in designing</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*I also need some ideas as to what can be other interesting ways*" - no: *you* define the "*interesting ways*," attempt to implement that and, should you encounter problems you can't fix, *then* come back and ask us about that specific problem.

Comment: Ya, sorry I had thought about some of them. eg. text coming along with the box, text slowly appearing after the box opened etc. I just wanted more ideas. Anyways, pls tell me how to implement these 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use transform with scale or translate:

scale:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
p {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#page1 {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #77d47f;
}
#about {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 width: 504px;
 height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#about_button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
}
#about_text {
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 height: 100px; 
  width:400px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
  transform-origin:0 0;
 transform: translateX(-4px) scale(0,1);
 overflow: hidden;
}
#about {
 top: 10%;
}

#about_button:hover + #about_text {
 
 transform: translateX(4px) scale(1,1);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="page1">
   <div id="about">
       <div id="about_button"></div>
    <div id="about_text"><p>Hi, I am a Computer Science student. I am interested in designing</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

translate:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
p {
 padding: 0 10px;
}
#page1 {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #77d47f;
}
#about {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5%;
 width: 504px;
 height: 100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#about_button {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: green;
 display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
#about_text {
 transition: transform 0.5s;
 height: 100px; 
  width:400px;
 background-color: blue;
 display: inline-block;
  transform-origin:0 0;
 transform: translateX(-450px);
 overflow: hidden;
}
#about {
 top: 10%;
}

#about_button:hover + #about_text {
 
 transform: translateX(-4px);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="page1">
   <div id="about">
       <div id="about_button"></div>
    <div id="about_text"><p>Hi, I am a Computer Science student. I am interested in designing</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the text as sibling to the background. Check out the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/gwbdrskg/

This is the HTML

```
<body>
        <div id="page1">
            <div id="about">
                <div id="about_button"></div>
                <div id="about_text">
        <div class="background"></div>
        <p class='text'>Hi, I am a Computer Science student. I am interested in designing</p>
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And the CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
p {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
#page1 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #77d47f;
}
#about {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    width: 504px;
    height: 100px;
}
#about_button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}
#about_text {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
#about_text .background {
    transition: width 0.5s;
    height: 100px;
    width: 0;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateX(-4px);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#about_text .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
#about {
    top: 10%;
}

#about_button:hover + #about_text .background {
    width: 400px;
}
```